# Multiple Where Clause Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I have the following syntax for Multiple Where Clause Conditions. The syntax is not being accepted by sql. Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to get the multiple conditions working.

```
   Declare @PopulationDate Datetime = '02-01-16';

DECLARE @Month1 AS integer;
DECLARE @Year1 as integer;
DECLARE @Month2 as integer;
Declare @Year2 as integer;
DECLARE @Month3 as integer;
Declare @Year3 as integer;
DECLARE @Month4 as integer;
Declare @Year4 as integer;
DECLARE @lastyear as integer;
Declare @CurrentMonth as DAte;
Set @CurrentMonth =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@PopulationDate)-1),@PopulationDate),101);


       set @Month1 = Month(DATEADD(MONTH, -4, @PopulationDate));
       set @Year1  = Year(DATEADD(Month, -4, @PopulationDate));
       set @Month2 = Month(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, @PopulationDate));
       set @Year2  = Year(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, @PopulationDate));
       set @Month3 = Month(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, @PopulationDate));
       set @Year3  = Year(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, @PopulationDate));
       set @Month4 = Month(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @PopulationDate));
       set @Year4  = Year(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @PopulationDate));

Declare @StartDate as Date 
= DATEADD(MONTH, -4, @PopulationDate);
 Declare @newdate as Date;--- pulls Start Date for probationer if in range of months being looked into. 
SET @newdate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@StartDate)-1),@StartDate),101);---- sets date 

with payment_year as
(
SELECT payr.ISN
      ,payr.PIN_NBR
      ,payr.PIN_SUF
      ,payr.PAYMENT_YEAR
      ,payr.RECORD_TYPE
      ,payr.PROB_LEVEL
      ,payr.PROB_OFFICER_NBR
  FROM [JVCS_CHILD_SUP_RDB].[dbo].[SCPR_PROBATION_ADA] payr
  where payr.record_type = 'mp'
  --order by PIN_NBR
)
, payment_Dates as
(
SELECT padt.ISN
      ,padt.PIN_NBR
      ,padt.PIN_SUF
      ,padt.PAYMENT_YEAR
      ,padt.RECORD_TYPE
      ,padt.PROB_LEVEL
      ,padt.PROB_OFFICER_NBR
      ,padt.PROB_DATE_ON
      ,padt.PROB_DATE_OFF
  from [JVCS_CHILD_SUP_RDB].[dbo].[SCPR_PROBATION_ADA] padt 
  where padt.RECORD_TYPE = 'pa'
  )
, Payments as
  (
  select py.isn
  ,py.PIN_NBR
  ,py.pin_suf
  ,py.PAYMENT_YEAR
  ,pd.PROB_DATE_ON
  ,pd.PROB_DATE_OFF
  ,pg.PAYMENT_GRP_INDEX
  ,pg.PAYMENT_MONTHLY_AMOUNT
  ,pg.PAYMENT_OWED

  from payment_year py
  left join payment_Dates pd on py.PIN_NBR = pd.PIN_NBR and py.PIN_SUF = pd.PIN_SUF
  right join [JVCS-CHILD-SUP-RDB].JVCS_CHILD_SUP_RDB.dbo.SCPR_PROBATION_ADA_PAYMENT_GRP pg on py.ISN = pg.isn
  where pd.PROB_DATE_OFF > @PopulationDate
  and pd.PROB_DATE_ON < @PopulationDate
  or py.PAYMENT_YEAR = Month(DATEADD(MONTH, -4, @PopulationDate));
  or py.PAYMENT_YEAR = Year(DATEADD(Month, -4, @PopulationDate));
  and py.PAYMENT_YEAR = Month(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, @PopulationDate));
  and py.PAYMENT_YEAR = Year(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, @PopulationDate));
  and py.PAYMENT_YEAR = Month(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, @PopulationDate));
  and py.PAYMENT_YEAR = Year(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, @PopulationDate));
  and py.PAYMENT_YEAR = Month(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @PopulationDate));
  and py.PAYMENT_YEAR = Year(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @PopulationDate));

 )

 Select * from Payments 
 order by PIN_NBR, PIN_SUF

--select month(@PopulationDate)
--select month(@StartDate)
--=Declare @PopulationDate as Date = DATEADD(Year, -1, @Populationdate); 

--Select @populationDate as PopDate, @startDate as StartDate, @Month1 as m1 , @Year1 as y1,  @Month2 as m2, @Year2 as y2, @Month3 as m3, @Year3 as y3, @Month4 as m4, @Year4 as y4
```

Comment: Even if the syntax were accepted, it would not return any rows, because the conditions are mutually exclusive.

Comment: What is the full syntax error you are getting? Aside from the syntax problem, using `and` with `PAYMENT_YEAR` in the way you've specified won't match because one column `py.PAYMENT_YEAR` cannot have more than one value in a row. Those may need to be `IN ()` or chained with `OR`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski here is the syntax error Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: @BegginerSQL Is it me or you have  `;` at the end of each `and` ...?

Comment: @BegginerSQL Wouldn't it be easier to put into a temporary table?

Comment: You are right @AndyK I do have ; at the end of each and.... I am not sure. I am stuck I have tried using or as well and no luck

Comment: Can you please explain what this query should return ?

Comment: @BegginerSQL you are too greedy in your approach. Start with 2 conditions first then increase with a third one and on and on. As far as I know, you only need one `;` : This is the way to say to the dbms , that it is the end of the query ...

Comment: @devlincarnate the query should return Years 2015 and 2016 it should right now it only returns 2016 I probably should post the rest of the syntax.

Comment: why are you also limiting by month if you want to get all Year 2015 and Year 2016 records?  also, please remove those ;  --they are definitely wrong.

Comment: I am defining by month because the client needs only 90 days of data at at a time @devlincarnate

Comment: can you give a sample of what the data in PAYMENT_YEAR looks like?  is it just a year?  or is the field name incorrect and it actually has a date in it?

Comment: 40020 476 2 2006 2006-04-11 00:00:00.000 2016-04-11 00:00:00.000 10 NULL
40020 476 2 2006 2006-04-11 00:00:00.000 2016-04-11 00:00:00.000 11 NULL
40020 476 2 2006 2006-04-11 00:00:00.000 2016-04-11 00:00:00.000 12 50.00
40020 476 2 2006 2006-04-11 00:00:00.000 2016-04-11 00:00:00.000 4 510.00 @devlincarnate

Comment: A semi-colon marks the end of a SQL query.   Everything after the semi-colon is interpreted as a new query.   Don't put a semi-colon in the middle of a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
where pd.PROB_DATE_OFF > @PopulationDate
  and pd.PROB_DATE_ON < @PopulationDate
    --allows months and years to be pulled for payment data (Dominqiue A. Anderson January 2016) 
    --- second bracket makes statement true
    and((pg.PAYMENT_GRP_INDEX = @Month1 
    and py.PAYMENT_YEAR = @Year1)
    or (pg.PAYMENT_GRP_INDEX = @Month2
    and py.PAYMENT_YEAR = @Year2) 
    or (pg.PAYMENT_GRP_INDEX = @Month3
    and py.PAYMENT_YEAR = @Year3)
    or (pg.PAYMENT_GRP_INDEX = @Month4
    and py.PAYMENT_YEAR = @Year4))  --- second bracket makes statement true   
 )

--  order by pd.PIN_NBR, pd.PIN_SUF, pg.PAYMENT_GRP_INDEX
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to get the past 90 days based PAYMENT_YEAR (which actually holds a datetime and not just a year),  then there's no need to compare month and year for the past 3 months.  You can use [DATEADD()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

[Here is a simple SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a570/2).

With your specific query, your WHERE condition should look something like:

```
WHERE pd.PROB_DATE_OFF > @PopulationDate
  AND pd.PROB_DATE_ON < @PopulationDate
  AND y.PAYMENT_YEAR >= DATEADD(DAY,-90,GETDATE())
```

This will return records that meet all 3 conditions.  If you need records that meet the first two conditions OR are within the past 30 days, use:

```
WHERE (pd.PROB_DATE_OFF > @PopulationDate
  AND pd.PROB_DATE_ON < @PopulationDate)
  OR y.PAYMENT_YEAR >= DATEADD(DAY,-90,GETDATE())
```

Comment: for some reason I am not getting any return still

Comment: if you remove all conditions in your WHERE clause, do you get results?

Comment: What is the original WHERE clause?  And with the original WHERE clause, are there results that have y.PAYMENT_YEAR within the last 90 days?  The example data you've shown for that field does not confirm this.  I see dates from 2016 and 2006, but nothing in the past 90 days.

Comment: Can you please share the solution?

Comment: I answered the question for you.